# How to parse html table in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-table

I'm newbie in parsing tables and regular expressions, can you help to parse this in python:

```
<table callspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody><tr>
    <td>1text&nbsp;2text</td>
    <td>3text&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4text&nbsp;5text</td>
    <td>6text&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I need the "3text" and "6text"

Comment: There's a standalone [html-table-parser-python3](https://github.com/ahobsonsayers/html-table-parser-python3); it works on table 5 in [Wikipedia Windturbines_in_Nederland](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windturbines_in_Nederland), BeautifulSoup doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `select()` and `select_one()` to get "3text" and "6text" like below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc='''
<table callspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody><tr>
    <td>1text&nbsp;2text</td>
    <td>3text&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4text&nbsp;5text</td>
    <td>6text&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
soup1 = soup.select('tr')

for i in soup1:
    print(i.select_one('td:nth-child(2)').text)
```

You can also use `find_all` method:

```
trs = soup.find('table').find_all('tr')

for i in trs:
    tds = i.find_all('td')
    print(tds[1].text)
```

Result:

```
3text 
6text
```

Answer (score 2):

best way is to use beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc='''
<table callspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody><tr>
    <td>1text&nbsp;2text</td>
    <td>3text&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4text&nbsp;5text</td>
    <td>6text&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

# finds all tr tags
for i in soup.find_all("tr"):
    # finds all td tags in tr tags
    for k in i.find_all("td"):
        # prints all td tags with a text format
        print(k.text)
```

in this case it prints

```
1text 2text
3text 
4text 5text
6text
```

but you can grab the texts you want with indexing. In this case you could just go with

```
# finds all tr tags
for i in soup.find_all("tr"):
    # finds all td tags in tr tags
    print(i.find_all("td")[1].text)
```

Answer (score 1):

using `pandas`

```
In [8]: import pandas as pd

In [9]: df =  pd.read_html(html_table)[0]

In [10]: df[1]
Out[10]:
0    3text
1    6text
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""
<table callspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody><tr>
    <td>1text&nbsp;2text</td>
    <td>3text&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4text&nbsp;5text</td>
    <td>6text&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for tr_soup in soup.find_all('tr'):
    td_soup = tr_soup.find_all('td')
    print(td_soup[1].text.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use pythons html.parser: https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

the custom parser class tracking a bit the state of the current parsing.
since you want the second cell of each row, when starting a row, each row resets the cell counter (index). each cell increments the counter.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.in_cell = False
        self.cell_index = -1

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'tr':
            self.cell_index = -1
        if tag == 'td':
            self.in_cell = True
            self.cell_index += 1
        # print("Encountered a start tag:", tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == 'td':
            self.in_cell = False
        # print("Encountered an end tag :", tag)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.in_cell and self.cell_index == 1:
            print(data.strip())

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('''<table callspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody><tr>
    <td>1text&nbsp;2text</td>
    <td>3text&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4text&nbsp;5text</td>
    <td>6text&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>''')
```

outputs:

```
> python -u "html_parser_test.py"
3text
6text
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your question has the `beautifulsoup` tag attached I am going to assume that you are happy using this module to tackle the problem you are having. My solution also makes use of the builtin `unicodedata` module to parse any escaped characters present within the HTML (e.g. `&nbsp;`).

To parse the table so that you have access to the second field from each row within the table (as per your question), please see the below code/comments.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import unicodedata

table = '''<table callspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody><tr>
    <td>1text&nbsp;2text</td>
    <td>3text&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4text&nbsp;5text</td>
    <td>6text&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(table, 'html.parser') # Parse HTML table 
tableData = soup.find_all('td') # Get list of all <td> tags from table
# Store normalized content (basically parse unicode characters, affecting spaces in this case) from every 2nd <td> tag from table to list 
output = [ unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', d.text) for i, d in enumerate(tableData) if i % 2 != 0 ]
```